# Is there a partly physical nature to infinitesimal limits that connects the utility of calculus with the quantized nature of small-scale physics?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-language, history-of-philosophy, philosophy-of-physics

One argument against calculus being physical is that since quantum mechanics has a quantized discrete nature, then physics does not truly have infinitesimal quantities. Yet, calculus and its mathematical limits may probably be inserted into every physics equation because everything is constantly moving and there is always a rate of change. Is there some part of abstract infinitesimal limits that is physical enough to justify calculus being inherent to physical nature?

Comment: Your so called ‘abstract infinitesimal limit’ is purely mathy, you need metaphysical principle such as Leibniz’s continuity principle claiming nature does not jump to justify calculus as usually understood being inherent to physical nature…

Comment: Quantized discrete nature?  Meaning that at the subatomic level, measurements of phenomena are discrete rather than continuous?  And if so, does it contradict calculus?  Possibly, at least at the subatomic level . . . that is, at this abstract level  of "reality."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quantum mechanics discovered the importance of discrete physical quantities to formulate the laws of the microworld. This discovery did not diminuish the importance of calculus with its integrable, continous, or differentiable functions.

Because quantum mechanics represents the physical observables by self-adjoint operators on the Hilbert space. The main mathematical tool to deal with these operators is the calculus from spectral theory, e.g. integrating against the spectral measure of a self-adjoint operator.

One of the most important operators in quantum mechanics, the  Hamiltonian of the Schroedinger hydrogenium, has a spectrum with both a continuous and a discrete part. The *discrete* part belongs to the bound states of the hydrogenium and their eigenvalues, while the *continuous* part belongs to its scattering states.